# ¿Qué me falta o Por qué la interfaz no me sale a darle run al proyecto?

Tags: jframe

Buenas estoy con intefaces, he creado un Jframe con 3 checkbox un botón de aceptar y una etiqueta tipo Label para el resultado. Esto es el poco código que tiene el proyecto en el botón aceptar

```
private void btnAceptarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    String mensaje = "Animales elegidos: ";
    if (chkPerro.isSelected()) {
        mensaje = mensaje + "Perro ";
    }
    if (chkGato.isSelected()) {
        mensaje = mensaje + "Gato ";
    }
    if (chkRaton.isSelected()) {
        mensaje = mensaje + "Raton ";
    }
    etiResultado.setText(mensaje);
}
```

Ahora bien cuando yo quiero probar el proyecto me salta la consola BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
Pero no me sale la interfaz para yo probar lo botones y eso y no se por qué es

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que al crear el proyecto se creo un main y entonces ejecutaba desde el main y no desde el jFrame